# Why is moveToFirst() returning false?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The condition `if(C.moveToFirst())` is returning to me false but idont know whay.

```
void Serch(View v, Layout layout){
  Uri Contacts = android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
  Cursor C = getContentResolver().query(Contacts, null, null, null, null);

  if(C == null)
    return;

  if(C.moveToFirst()){
    do{
      String display_ContactsName = getValue(C,android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

       if(Check(display_ContactsName) == false)
         continue;
       break;
    } while(C.moveToNext());
  }
}
```

Comment: Cursor has no rows ... end of story ..

Comment: how can i fix it? (iam new on java iam learning so it will be nice if you will explain to me (: )

Comment: there is nothing to explain ... there is no contacts on your phone/emulator

Comment: ooo ok sorry sorry igot in i recreated my emulator xD

Comment: Do you have the permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> in your XML? If not you will not access any contacts and it will return False as the cursor is empty.  Also have a read over this: http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html

Comment: yes.. (its working!!)

Comment: Glad to hear it, can you let us know what the issue was so if others have this they know what to do to fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29):

> This method will return false if the cursor is empty.